# Panda robot using denavit-hartenberg parameters matlab error

Tags: matlab

I am trying to answer a question which requires me to create a panda robot using Denavit-Hartenberg parameters and deriving the forwards kinematics model. I have written a form of code but for some reason I’m getting the error:

```
Error using assert
Insufficient columns in q

Error in SerialLink/plot (line 206)
    assert(numcols(qq) == n, 'RTB:SerialLink:plot:badarg', 'Insufficient columns in q')

Error  (line 41)
robot.plot([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);  % Provide initial joint angles for plotting
```

This is my code:

```matlab
% Define symbolic variables
syms q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7

% Define Denavit-Hartenberg parameters for Panda robot
d = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

alpha = [0, -pi/2, pi/2, -pi/2, pi/2, -pi/2, 0];

theta = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7];

% Initialize transformation matrix
T = eye(4);

% Iterate through joints to compute transformation matrices
for i = 1:7
    % Compute Denavit-Hartenberg transformation matrix
    A = [cos(theta(i)), -sin(theta(i))*cos(alpha(i)),  sin(theta(i))*sin(alpha(i)), a(i)*cos(theta(i));

         sin(theta(i)),  cos(theta(i))*cos(alpha(i)), -cos(theta(i))*sin(alpha(i)), a(i)*sin(theta(i));

                      0,                 sin(alpha(i)),                 cos(alpha(i)),                d(i);
                      0,                               0,                               0,                  1];
    
    % Update transformation matrix
    T = T * A;
end

% Display the final transformation matrix for translation in the end-effector
disp('Final Transformation Matrix:');
disp(T);

% Define the robot using Revolute and Link objects
L(1) = Revolute('a', a(1), 'alpha', alpha(1), 'd', d(1), 'offset', 0);

L(2) = Revolute('a', a(2), 'alpha', alpha(2), 'd', d(2), 'offset', 0);
% Define the rest of the joints...

% Create a SerialLink object
robot = SerialLink(L, 'name', 'Panda Robot');

% Create a joint configuration with symbolic variables
q_sym = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7];

% Display the robot model
robot.plot([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);  % Provide initial joint angles for plotting

% Experiment with the "teach" method
robot.teach();

% Forward Kinematics using "fkine"
endEffectorPose = robot.fkine([45, 45, -90, 50, 60, 90, -30] * pi/180);

% Display the end-effector pose
disp('End-Effector Pose:');
disp(endEffectorPose);

% Inverse Kinematics using "ikine"
q_guess = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];  % Initial guess for joint angles
jointAngles = robot.ikine(endEffectorPose, 'q0', q_guess);

% Display Inverse Kinematics Result
disp('Inverse Kinematics Result:');
disp(jointAngles);

% Animation loop (adjust the step size and range accordingly)
for i = 1:10:360
    % Update joint angles for animation
    robot.plot([i, i, -90, 50, 60, 90, -30] * pi/180);
    pause(0.1);  % Pause to create animation effect
end
```

Comment: @Adriaan thanks for the help, i used the edited code but it came up with the same error for the robot.plot function